# Adding achievements and Google Play Games services

Tags: android, google-play-games

It was supposed to be easy, but it's so hard...

I'm working with eclipse. I'm trying to go by [this site](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).

In here it says (Setting up your game project) that I need to make my main Activity extend `BaseGameUtils`.

I go into the download link, and for some reason I see many projects. I download one that contains what I need, and from everything being downloaded (many projects), I pick the right one and import it (for some reason it contains it's sources not in `src` directory but in `java`, so I needed to add it to the build path... And it's being called `main` so it's already exists...)

In addition, I also install `google-play-service-lib` and import it too. Then I make it a project that `BaseGameUtils` depends on.

Now I make my `MainActivity` (Main class) exdends `BaseGameActivity` and get an error:

```
The hierarchy of the type Main is inconsistent.
```

If I go into `BaseGameActivity` I see an error there -

```
The import com.google.android.gms.common.api cannot be resolved
```

Which makes

```
The hierarchy of the type BaseGameActivity is inconsistent.
```

So it doesn't know which package to reference, and so do I...
Using eclipse_compat not helped - it did the same thing - at first not knowing `com.google.android` and after using `google-play-services-lib` makes `com.google.android.gms.common.api` unknown.

Then I removed the project dependency of `google-play-services` and replaced it with a jar dependency. That solved the unknown problem of `com.google.android.gms.common.api`, but made `com.google.android.gms.games.request` unknown.
Trying to use android studio didn't help - throws

```
Android Dex: [] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$SerializationProxyV1;
```

on compile. I think it means `google-play-services-lib` because removing it solves *this* problem, only now it can't find `com.google.example`...

It was supposed to be really easy (just add a project and extend it) - Why is it this hard (don't get me started on adding a record table to the project...)?!

**So to sum up:**
I want to add achievements into my app, and I don't know how... I tried many things (written) and came across many errors. I just want to be able to extend BaseGameActivity / add BaseGameUtils without compile errors (where are the required classes?). In case Android Studio could help, I want to be able to solve my compile problem.

**Edit:** Now google changed their guide, so I don't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong. The files in the java folder (in which BaseGameActivity.java is) were suppose to be placed in your project and not as part of library project. Place it in your project and then reference the google-play-services-lib project as a library project in your project. All should work fine.

Comment: The import com.google.android.gms.common.api cannot be resolved... where is it? I have a google-play-services-lib project, but he only has UnusedStub in it...

Comment: did you reference the library project it in your main project?

Comment: Yes - I added the project, to no avail. see here: 
http://postimg.org/image/g1fud5e3j/ - I use the project, google-play-services.jar and google-play-services-lib.jar...

Comment: No, not here. you should as the project in the Android Tab not this java build tab. Remove this and go to android and down there you will see add library project and add these two projects over there.

Comment: still no good... I added in android tab, and removed the java build, but still... Now, In BaseGameActivity (That is in my project)  I get: "The import com.google.android.gms.common cannot be resolved"... http://postimg.org/image/6155ci2pr/